# Create an array of object literals in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using a jQuery plugin to sort columns - [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

It lets you disable headers using options. At the moment I disable headers 2 & 3 by passing options when initialising the plugin:

```
$("#mytable").tablesorter({
  headers: {
    1: {  
      sorter: false 
    },
    2: { 
      sorter: false 
    }
  } 
});
```

I'd like to do it dynamically, by checking if a class "header" exists; if not I would disable the functionality.

[Here is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MYts/)

Any idea on how I could do it dynamically?

Comment: Check out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) in which you can just add a class name of `sorter-false` to the header to dynamically enable or disable sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the `theade th` elements without the class `header` and then create a dynamic object like

```
var headers = {};
$('#mytable thead th').not('.header').each(function () {
    headers[$(this).index()] = {
        sorter: false
    };
})

console.log(headers)

$("#mytable").tablesorter({
    headers: headers
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KQNRg/)

Comment: Thanks, works fine. Only error in your code is that sorter should be set to false. I'll accept your answer as soon as you update. Thanks for the quick response!